# ValueError: Cannot assign "<User: salman>": "DoctorProfile.user" must be a "Doctor" instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, error-handling, django-registration

## I'm trying to register two types of users the Doctor and the Patient but when I tried I got the following error which made me feel like I'm lost because I really don't know what's happning

thi is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rachi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request).....
 ..
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot assign "<User: salman>": "DoctorProfile.user" must be a "Doctor" instance.
```

## This is my code

*my models.py*

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_doctor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_patient = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Doctor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    number_phone = models.CharField(
        _('االهاتف :'), max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.user.username)




class DoctorProfile (models.Model):

    
    }
    user = models.OneToOneField(Doctor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)


    

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(DoctorProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.name)

    # def get_absolute_url(self):
    #     return reverse("doctor_detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})


def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):

    if kwargs['created']:
        DoctorProfile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])


post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)


class Patient(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="الاسم ")
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.user.username)
```

please tell me where is the probleme

Comment: Why do you have a `Doctor` and `DoctorProfile` model?

Comment: because the doctor must have a profile

Comment: but why not store the data of the "profile" of the doctor in `Doctor`? The only reason why people often *make* a profile model is *not* to subclass `User`, but here you basically did that already. By making an extra model, you only create extra joins, etc.

Comment: is there another solution? because it will take too much time

Comment: too much time? Not normalizing the database properly is a bumpy road to a lot of trouble: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: okay, thank you I will try it. I hope I can get your social media like Instagram or something like that for more explanation

Comment: You are trying to save an instance of `User` type to field `DoctorProfile.user` field. While you should create a `Doctor` instance using that `User` instance/data and then assign it to `DoctorProfile.user = Doctor(user=User)` ... similar to this.